# Do we need to make sure getDerivedStateFromProps is not recursive?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand the new React lifecycle methods and have trouble figuring out some details. In React docs for [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) it says:

> getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked right before calling the render
>   method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should
>   return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.
>
> Note that this method is **fired on every render, regardless of the
>   cause**. This is in contrast to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps, which
>   only fires when the parent causes a re-render and not as a result of a
>   local setState.

(emphasis mine)

If I understand correctly, if I just derive state from props and return it (as the name suggests we should do), I will trigger an endless loop, because `this.state` will update, which will trigger re-render, which will call `getDerivedStateFromProps`, which will return new state update,...

Do we need to make sure that we only return state update if the changes differ from the old state, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

> I will trigger an endless loop, because this.state will update, which will trigger re-render, which will call `getDerivedStateFromProps`

That is not correct. `getDerivedStateFromProps` is called before render not after render. Quote from the react doc (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops):

> getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked right before calling the render method

So technically, whatever you return from `getDerivedStateFromProps` will be included in the state update in the upcoming render. The render will not trigger another `getDerivedStateFromProps` so there won't be an infinite loop. I think the situation you worried about might happen with `componentDidUpdate` if you call `setState` within it.

However, even though an infinite loop will not be triggered, it doesn't mean it is good to derive state from props. In fact, you should try to avoid that. See this blog: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Generally, you should compute whatever you need on the fly in the render method if you could. That will ensure the data is always correct and up-to-date.